# How to lengthen a full_joined dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a couple of different datasets that I need to lengthen after I `full_join` them, but can't figure out how to merge the columns right.

```
dataset 1 (pre-join):
            error  phase Freq instructions
1              C1  first    2     implicit
2         C1 drop  first    2     implicit
3              C2  first   10     implicit
4      C2 C3 swap  first   10     implicit
5         C2 drop  first    5     implicit
6              C3  first   30     implicit
7         C3 drop  first   12     implicit
8      CC initial  first   50     implicit
9       CC medial  first   26     implicit
10          CCVVC  first    0     implicit
[...]


dataset 2 (pre-join):
1              C1  first    1     explicit
2   C1 C2 C3 swap  first    1     explicit
3         C1 drop  first    1     explicit
4              C2  first    5     explicit
5      C2 C3 swap  first    5     explicit
6         C2 drop  first    1     explicit
7              C3  first   14     explicit
8         C3 drop  first    3     explicit
9      CC initial  first   67     explicit
10      CC medial  first   37     explicit
[...]

joined dataset (full_join(df1, df2, by = "error"):
             error phase.x Freq.x instructions.x phase.y Freq.y instructions.y
1               C1   first      2       implicit   first      1       explicit
2               C1   first      2       implicit  second      1       explicit
3               C1   first      2       implicit    test      0       explicit
4          C1 drop   first      2       implicit   first      1       explicit
5          C1 drop   first      2       implicit  second      0       explicit
6          C1 drop   first      2       implicit    test      1       explicit
7               C2   first     10       implicit   first      5       explicit
8               C2   first     10       implicit  second      6       explicit
9               C2   first     10       implicit    test      2       explicit
10      C2 C3 swap   first     10       implicit   first      5       explicit
[...]
```

I'm looking for four columns total: error, phase, Freq, and instructions, but I'm not sure how to set up the arguments so that phase.y is included in the phase.x column, and the same for the instructions columns, with the appropriate error type and error frequency associated with the error-phase-instructions combination. I also want to see which errors had a frequency of 0 in each instruction type or experiment phase (hence full_join).

**EDIT**
My intended output is formatted something like this:

```
            error  phase Freq instructions
              C1  first    2     implicit
              C1  first    1     explicit
   C1 C2 C3 swap  first    0     implicit # this is a row that didn't exist in df1
   C1 C2 C3 swap  first    1     explicit
         C1 drop  first    2     implicit
         C1 drop  first    1     explicit
              C2  first   10     implicit
              C2  first    5     explicit
      C2 C3 swap  first   10     implicit
      C2 C3 swap  first    5     explicit
         C2 drop  first    5     implicit
         C2 drop  first    1     explicit
              C3  first   30     implicit
              C3  first   14     explicit
         C3 drop  first   12     implicit
         C3 drop  first    3     explicit
      CC initial  first   50     implicit
      CC initial  first   67     explicit
       CC medial  first   26     implicit
       CC medial  first   37     explicit
           CCVVC  first    0     implicit
           CCVVC  first    0     explicit # this is a row that didn't exist in df2
[...]
```

**/EDIT**

I'm really just not quite sure where to start with pivot_longer, since that's my first thought.  Are there other options?

I'm starting with something like

```
df.long <- pivot_longer(df3, !error)
```

but I can't figure out how to appropriately merge the columns that are from df1 and 2, and I haven't found any advice that will allow me to do so once the datasets have been joined.

Comment: Maybe just `dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)`?

Comment: right, so what that gets me is the two dataframes on top of each other, but I also want a count of the errors that occur with implicit instructions that don't occur with the explicit instructions, and vice versa, so that I can do that comparison. that's why I'm doing the full_join and hoping to lengthen that dataframe.

Comment: You can still do that after binding. Look into `dplyr::group_by()` and `dplyr::summarize()` or `dplyr::count()`

Comment: I understand. I've looked into those and they still don't quite get me where I need to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As AndS said, since you're wanting to append new values to the end of the already existing columns, not add new columns, you want `bind_rows` (or `add_row`, if you were adding them one at a time):

```
library(dplyr)

# you could also, if you wanted, add a column for the dataset #, if you wish to, so you can still keep track of which dataset each row originally came from. You'd do that by (for example) going df1 <- mutate(df1, dataset = 1)
df.long <- bind_rows(df1, df2)

# for each instruction type and experiment phase, and error combination, which had a frequency of 0? 
summarise(df.long, Freq = sum(Freq), .by = c("error", "phase", "instructions")) |> 
  filter(Freq == 0)

# Output:
  error phase instructions Freq
1 CCVVC first     implicit    0
```

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear in the text, but same comment here as under AndS's. the crux of the question I'm trying to answer in this data is if there are errors (and how many) that occurred with one set of instructions and not the other, so having that showing in the data to analyze it (hence full_join) is very important and doesn't occur with just binding the rows.

Comment: I don't think that was clear at all

Comment: If you can, in the future include an intended output. As no one knows what the context for your example is, even your explanation now doesn't really clear things up either.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I actually figured it out and it's because I'm a doofus who doesn't comment their code when it worked for a very similar but simpler dataset. I wasn't full_joining by enough columns in the first place. Here's what works:

```
# i thought i was being smart by adding an 'instructions' column to these datasets, but it turns out it's just totally extraneous. adding the suffix ends up being fine to distinguish between the instruction types for graphing purposes. to join like I want to, I need to join by ALL relevant columns. the suffixation gets you NAs where an error doesn't occur, which you then replace with zeros two lines down.

df3 <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c("error", "instructions", "phase"), suffix = c("-imp", "-exp"))

df3.long <- pivot_longer(df3, -c(error, instructions, phase))

# if there are NAs, change them to 0 so they can be graphed for comparison
df3.long[is.na(df3.long)] = 0
```

This results in a tibble that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 282 × 5
   error      phase instructions name     value
   <chr>      <chr> <chr>        <chr>    <int>
 1 C1         first implicit     Freq-imp     2
 2 C1         first implicit     Freq-exp     0
 3 C1 drop    first implicit     Freq-imp     2
 4 C1 drop    first implicit     Freq-exp     0
 5 C2         first implicit     Freq-imp    10
 6 C2         first implicit     Freq-exp     0
 7 C2 C3 swap first implicit     Freq-imp    10
 8 C2 C3 swap first implicit     Freq-exp     0
 9 C2 drop    first implicit     Freq-imp     5
10 C2 drop    first implicit     Freq-exp     0
# ℹ 272 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Without the value = 0 rows, it's very weird for the graphs I'm trying to make (bar graphs; for anything without corresponding data, there's a fat bar that looks weird). Instead, I can now get a graph that looks like this:
[bar graph with errors across the X axis, count on the Y axis, and faceted by instruction type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wzBL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I still think you're over complicating things and you just need `bind_rows`. If you want to expand the groups then follow up with `complete`. In the future I recommend outlining the ultimate goal or the motivation in the question. That helps to direct the answers towards suitable solutions to your problem.

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(df1, df2) |>
  complete(error, phase, instructions, fill = list(Freq = 0))
#> # A tibble: 22 x 4
#>    error         phase instructions  Freq
#>    <chr>         <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
#>  1 C1            first explicit         1
#>  2 C1            first implicit         2
#>  3 C1 C2 C3 swap first explicit         1
#>  4 C1 C2 C3 swap first implicit         0
#>  5 C1 drop       first explicit         1
#>  6 C1 drop       first implicit         2
#>  7 C2            first explicit         5
#>  8 C2            first implicit        10
#>  9 C2 C3 swap    first explicit         5
#> 10 C2 C3 swap    first implicit        10
#> # i 12 more rows
```